# Should “to be” be conjugated in “I am learning to be alpha”?

Tags: word-usage

*Learning* is a present form and *to be* a future form. But *being* is a present form. Which is correct in the following sentence?

> I am learning ___ alpha.

Where ___ is *to be* or *being*?

Comment: 'to be' is infinitive.  'being' and 'Learning' are gerunds. 'am learning' is present continuous.

Comment: clickbait title

Comment: @user31415 no. i asked "to be, or not to be, i.e. something else"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"To be" is the infinitive, rather than the future form.

(To express "to be" in future tense, you place modal verb "will" in front, or conjugate "to go" in present continous tense in front. For example - I will be, you are going to be)

The auxiliary "am learning" must be followed by the infinitive, so option 1 is correct.